# awk to check duplicate and incremental count

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to check every `field` level duplicated or not then populate `"Yes"` if it duplicated else `"No"`.
Then populate the incremental count of occurrences like `counter` for that field. Then check the entire row is duplicated or unique.

Input.csv

```
Name,Age,Sub
abc,10,eee
def,20,csc
abc,30,mec
ghi,40,sss
abc,10,eee
def,10,csc
```

Desired Output:

```
Name,Age,Sub,Name_Dup,Name_Counter,Age_Dup,Age_Counter,Sub_Dup,Sub_Counter,EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter
abc,10,eee,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1
def,20,csc,Yes,1,No,1,Yes,1,No,1
abc,30,mec,Yes,2,No,1,No,1,No,1
ghi,40,sss,No,1,No,1,No,1,No,1
abc,10,eee,Yes,3,Yes,2,Yes,2,Yes,2
def,10,csc,Yes,2,Yes,3,Yes,2,No,1
```

searched similar cases and Find `uniq -c` command and `!seen[$1]++` seems generating unique values/lines only . Please suggest..

**Edit#1:**

Ed Morton, sorry for the poor post, I have edited the post. kindly check now. In real time scenarios , we are getting the quote from our supplier like country wise, region wise , product wise, product code wise , rate and cost information for A-Z destinations
 So , we will not be able to decide which duplicated rows need to be delete, post the above population we can check and take some decision quickly.

For example, I am trying to check is there any duplicate information in the field $1. Under Name field, "abc" appears three times , "def" appears two times,"ghi" appear one time. So if any word is not repeated more than one time is considered as "Name_Dup=No" and count of appears is "Name_Counter=1" (i.e ghi)

where "abc" appears 3 times , so duplicated as "Yes" when it appears first time count is "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=1" , when it appears second time "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=2,  when it appears 3rd time "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=3

Then need to check $2, $3 .. till $NF and $0 ..

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: I am using this command for awk ' { print $0 "," ++count[$1] }' then changing the fields value to get the ouput

Comment: Yeah, but that obviously doesn't solve the problem. What did you tried then?

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'function hasDupe(arr, f){ 
         return (arr[f]>1)? "Yes":"No" 
     }
     BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     NR==1{ next }
     NR==FNR{ names[$1]++; ages[$2]++; subs[$3]++; all[$0]++; next }
     {
         if (FNR==1) 
             print $0,"Name_Dup,Name_Counter,Age_Dup,Age_Counter,Sub_Dup,Sub_Counter,EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter"; 
         else
             print $0,hasDupe(names,$1),++n[$1],hasDupe(ages,$2),++a[$2],hasDupe(subs,$3),++s[$3],hasDupe(all,$0),++all_lines[$0] 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
Name,Age,Sub,Name_Dup,Name_Counter,Age_Dup,Age_Counter,Sub_Dup,Sub_Counter,EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter
abc,10,eee,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1
def,20,csc,Yes,1,No,1,Yes,1,No,1
abc,30,mec,Yes,2,No,1,No,1,No,1
ghi,40,sss,No,1,No,1,No,1,No,1
abc,10,eee,Yes,3,Yes,2,Yes,2,Yes,2
def,10,csc,Yes,2,Yes,3,Yes,2,No,1
```

Comment: RomanPerekhrest,  Thanks a lot for support, Kindly advise how to make it generic. Actual input files No of fields used to be vary like 10 fields, 12 etc

Comment: @AVN, welcome. "generic" solution - it's another story which requires another extended solution. At the moment, the current solution works for your current input and gives the desired result

Comment: `^1` for coming up with an answer. I have absolutely no clue what the question is about!

Comment: Ed Morton, I have edited the post, kindly check now

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks. Frankly speaking, I've understood the question not by initial description, but rather by intuition

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, I am running the above command via cygwin, I am not getting any output or error message. Please advise